# Open-Source Trigonometric Equation Simplifiers (preferably C-based)?

Tags: c, algorithm, open-source, trigonometry, simplify

I have done some searching around the internet trying to find some form of example code that will allow me to simplify trigonometric equations. In my mathematics course-work this year I am required to simplify trigonometric equations, and I intend on adapting the code to work with my TI-89 Titanium CAS, to use in replacement of the tCollect and tExpand functions (that can't seem to get the job done quite as nicely as I'd like it to).

As I can't really find all too much information on the matter I'd like to know if there is any  code (preferably C-based) that will help me to simplify these kinds of equations. If not, what kind of algorithm would be best looking into to code myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very powerful system that seems to have the functionality you need is Maxima, an open source computer algebra system. The following manpage describes trigexapand and trigreduce, which would seem to be roughly what you're looking for.

http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_15.html

It's in Lisp rather than C, but consider that an adventure :)

Comment: http://maxima.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/maxima/maxima/src/trgred.lisp?view=markup

I'm glad it's centralised to one location but... gahh lisp haha

Answer (score 0):

[Eigenmath](http://eigenmath.sourceforge.net/) is a handy little computer algebra system.

You might find something relevant in [Eigenmath's source code](http://eigenmath.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eigenmath/eigenmath/).

Comment: Sorry, this is not relevant as there is no function in the program that helps simplify sin(x)/cos(x) -> tan(x) even.

Answer (score 0):

The HP49/50 series calculators have a variety of trig manipulation functions that may do a better job than the TI-89. The CAS for the HP calculators is open source, but written in an obscure language. You'd be better off checking out the next CAS written by that guy: [Giac/Xcas](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/english.html), written in C++.